# Conditional comments in Internet Explorer 10 and 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In  Internet Explorer 10 and 11 Conditional comments  are possible ?  If not what is the alternative solution ?

Comment: Why do you need conditional comments in IE10 and 11? There are CSS hacks using media queries, but I have not needed to use any in my development.

Comment: When i use main css file site seems ok ..but button, form not working I mean when I click its freeze

Comment: No, conditional comments are not supported in IE>9, and no replacing features available. Also, CCS hardly freezes a page, maybe you should post a new question, and ask what you really need?

Comment: Thanks Teemu  for the information . Actually my sites form and buttons are not clickable in IE11 . They are freezes ,but when i remove css  i can click or can write in form element .